# Selected number of records from database in DB2

Tags: db2

I have to fetch only 50 records at a time from database (DB2), for this I have been using `Row_Number` but now the persons are telling that this `Row_Number` is not stable and has bugs in it so now I have to write a different query for the same as I have to fetch only 50 records at a time.

So please can any body help me out for the same?

Thanks in advance.

The query which I have been using is

```
SELECT PLC.* 
FROM
     (SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRDLN_CTLG_OID) AS Row,
          PRDLN_CTLG_OID, 
          PRODUCT_LINE_OID      AS  PRODUCT_LINE_OID, 
          RTRIM(CATALOG_ID)             AS  CATALOG_ID,
      FROM 
          PROD_LINE_CATALOG 
      WHERE 
          PRODUCT_LINE_OID = :productLineOID AND ACTV_IND = 1 
      ORDER BY CATALOG_ID) PLC
WHERE  
    Row >= :startIndex AND Row <= :endIndex
ORDER BY 
    PLC.CATALOG_ID DESC 
WITH UR
```

Comment: you have asked twelve(12) questions and received twenty three (23) answers so far over eleven (11) months, but you haven't accepted any. How about rewarding those you found useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the fetch clause

```
FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY
```

**edit**

It looks like you use a startIndex and endIndex value. I realize you compare these to `Row`, but do you have another index to compare? If not, and you insist on moving from Row_Number, maybe the table needs another index.

```
Select PLC.* From (Select omitting row_number())
Where yournewindex >= startIndex
Fetch first 50 rows only
```

Comment: and unlike the LIMIT or TOP clause which goes at the beginning of the query, the FETCH clause goes at the end

Comment: David but the fetch record will always give me the first N rows only from database and if I want to achieve records in between something like 50 to 100 it will definitely will not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone already answered that question. You are asking for pagination if I'm not wrong.

[Fastest most/efficient way to do pagination with SQL searching DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997838/fastest-most-efficient-way-to-do-pagination-with-sql-searching-db2)