# Pagination query(SQL) in AS400/DB2

Tags: php, sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have been working on try to create php web-based paging for our tables
which have over a million rows.

Based on what I have read, I have 3 options

1. retrieve all rows in resultset - not possiblefor me coz of the size
2. retrieve 1000 rows, store in temp table and create an iterator for
   it and page through it - too many queries - too many inserts!!
3. run a query each time if someone opts page forward or backwards

Right now I am trying to get option 3 working.
I have the first page showing up as
"select * from accout order by acct fetch first 10 rows only"
Page next
"select * from account where acct>(last record) order by acct fetch
first 10 only"
page last record
"select * from account where acct=(select max(acct) from account)"

The problem is showing the previous page and i really would appreciate
help in this.

Comment: Along with the actual data, you need to keep track of two things: the first value of the incrementing ID that appears on the page (which appears to be `acct`) and how many items to display per page. Once you have that, prepare two queries: one for the "Previous" button and one for the "Next" button.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY acct) AS RowNum
    FROM 
      account
  ) AS Data
WHERE 
  RowNum BETWEEN 100 AND 110;
```

First, you should get rid of the `SELECT *`. Select only the fields you need.

Place an index on `acct`, this will help the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY acct)` construct.

Use a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account` to determine how many pages you will have.

Also read [Fastest most/efficient way to do pagination with SQL searching DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997838/fastest-most-efficient-way-to-do-pagination-with-sql-searching-db2)

Answer (score 0):

The LIMIT..OFFSET solution is supported in DB2 10+.. For older versions, you have to enable the MySQL compatibility with:

```
$ db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
$ db2stop
$ db2start
```

in db2cmd in order to use that syntax.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 10, 1;
```

try the limit and offset in mysql..

this mostly use in creating pagination

Comment: I am trying to do it in DB2 OR AS400 not in mysql.