# Pagination in the AS400 SQL

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to do the pagination for the as400 table which is of version 6 and release 1

I'm using this query:

```
select * from AJSTYLES91.CLIENT 
ORDER BY CNUM
LIMIT 2 [OFFSET 2];
```

but is not working so can any one suggest me the proper query to use please!!!

Comment: Hi Kavana. Some people on StackOverflow asked similar question and got responses, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038790/1206341

Comment: IBM i V6R1 is old, you are using an OS that's only 2 years younger than Windows Vista. V6R1 doesn't understand `limit ... offset`. Many things are missing in this version, jump to v7r3 if you can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pagination query(SQL) in AS400/DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036838/pagination-querysql-in-as400-db2)

Answer (score 1):

I think `declare global temporary table` works in `v6r1`. You can select all of your rows into a temporary table.

```
declare global temporary table orders as ( 
/* open orders */ 
select    a.orhordnum ordnum, a.orhshpnam shipname 
from      dwhpf30c a
where     a.orhcmp = 'N'
order by  a.orhshpnam 
 ) with data with replace
```

then use `rrn` on that resulting table to calculate the page number and select on that page.

```
select     a.ordnum, a.shipname, rrn(a),              
           decimal( (rrn(a) -1) / 30,5,0) + 1 pageNum 
from       qtemp/orders a                             
where       decimal( (rrn(a) -1) / 30,5,0) + 1 = 5
```